# change color of link when clicked in Java

Tags: java, css, swing, hyperlink, jeditorpane

Okay, I know the title of the post is very familiar. I saw a lot of posts on this subject, but non of them covered the code in Java.   I have this `HyperlinkListener` class :

```
private void editorpaneHyperlinkUpdate(javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent evt) {
   // TODO add your handling code here:
   if (evt.getEventType() ==
                       HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                                    try {
                                        try {
    java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(evt.getURL().toURI());
                                           } catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MyAssistantGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                        } 
                                 catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MyAssistantGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
              System.out.println("Open browser: " + evt.getURL());
```

I tried to add Style-sheet to my `JEditorPane` and then add `a:active {color: #f00;}`, but it does not work. Then i saw in the API that java does not support `a:active/hoover`..etc.
Can you give me suggestions, on how to change the color when the user clicks the link?

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  And leave out the 'every other line as white space' - thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In the listener you can get position in the text. Then cast your `JEditorPane's` `Document` to `StyledDocument` and use `getCharacterElement()` passing the offset you have. For the `Element` you can change attributes e.g background or foreground using `setCharacterAttributes()` method.

Comment: Can you give me an example, because I can't seem to understand how to get the position in the text? I can get the X and Y where the mouse clicked, but how can I specify the color for the whole text of the link?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to StanislavL's answer, by searching a bit I was able to tweak that.

Also note that you may need to take care of the listener order if for some reason other code contributes listeners to this `JEditorPane`.

The code is kotlin but the snippet show the gist of what need to be done.

This is the listener code.

```kotlin
class MyHyperlinkListener : HyperlinkListener {
    override fun hyperlinkUpdate(e: HyperlinkEvent) {
        val editorPane = e.inputEvent.component as? JEditorPane ?: return
        val styledDocument = editorPane.document as? HTMLDocument ?: return
        e.sourceElement ?: return

        val characterElement = styledDocument.getCharacterElement(e.sourceElement.startOffset)

        val style = when (e.eventType) {
            HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ENTERED -> styledDocument.getStyle("a:hover")
            HyperlinkEvent.EventType.EXITED -> styledDocument.getStyle("a.wildcard")
            else -> return
        }

        styledDocument.setCharacterAttributes(
            characterElement.startOffset,
            characterElement.endOffset - characterElement.startOffset,
            style,
            false
        )
    }
}
```

> This listener by the way could be used to get the rectangle of the element, e.g having the `y` coordinate to show a popup strictly above this element.
>
> ```kotlin
> (e.inputEvent as MouseEvent).point.also { p ->
>     p.y = e.inputEvent.component.y
>     (editorPane as? JEditorPane)?.let { jEditorPane ->
>         p.y = jEditorPane.modelToView2D(e.sourceElement.startOffset).y.toInt()
>     }
> }
> ```

But to apply the rules they need to be existing in the doc

```kotlin
(doc as HTMLDocument).styleSheet.addRule(
    """
    a { 
        text-decoration: none; 
    }
    body {
        font-style: normal; 
    }
    a.special {
        color: ...;
        background-color: ...;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
        color: ...;
        background-color: ...;
        text-decoration: none;
    }""".trimIndent()
)
```